# Hdd not showing in Finder

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, finder, osx-el-capitan

I have a USB HDD that it was working normally.

I've deleted a lot of files. Then I remove the USB (in a unsafe way) and then it stopped showing in Finder.

When I try to open Disk Utility, it loads forever.

When I remove remove the USB cable and plug again, it show my HDD, but like it's empty:

[image]

When I run "First Aid", it shows me this error:

[image]

I'm using El Capitan.

Maybe i've deleted some files that helps the HD to mount as well

Comment: I'd recommend you try using a different USB cable to connect the external drive with, @Cleyton. You should also try plugging it to another USB port on your Mac. Have you tried to diagnose the HDD's health and SMART status from the Disk utility? I'd suggest you [test the drive for defects from there](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=866). Hope this helps. Keep me posted.

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD Thanks, but i've tried but like the print shows, it's not showing the driver for me.

Comment: This looks unfortunate, @Cleyton! :( I'd suggest you attempt to plug the HDD to a different Mac OS X computer and see if you'd be able to access it from there. Have you tried using a different USB cable as well? The unsafe removal of the external drive might have corrupted the file system and possibly the HDD itself, especially if it was still reading/writing data. I'd also consider contacting the drive manufacturer's customer support for assistance with this. Tampering with the HDD physically will void the warranty (if still covered), so be careful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a series of steps to not lost my files.

First, I've used [this software](http://www.stellarinfo.com/data-recovery-mac.php) to recover all data.

I've also used Disk Utility. At first, it seemed to me that went wrong.

I've started using Image recovery from Stellar software and suddenly this message came up:

[image]

I think this message it's from Disk Utility.

But now I've made backup from all data and I'll format the disk.

Comment: That's great. Seems like Image Recovery did the job. 'll have to look into it. This last happened to me when I used a hard drive for TimeMachine backups through the Netgear Nighthawk router... This tends to happen a lot when the drive isn't ejected properly. Anyway, congrats!

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to me in the past. It's intermittent, so it's hard to track the issue, but may I offer a few options for troubleshooting the problem.
This solutions uses Terminal. Go to your spotlight and type "Terminal" and open the application.

List the current drives:

1. Plug in your USB drive. Wait at least 30 seconds.
2. type `diskutil list`
3. Go through the list of drives and determine if your drive is showing up

It should show up, since it is showing up for you in DiskUtility. This tells me that it isn't mounting properly. Try mounting it now:

1. If unable to mount as a regular user, do a `sudo` when executing the command: `diskutil mount /dev/disk#s#` , where disk# is your i/o port and s# is the actual drive. So be sure you get those numbers right by following the steps above.
2. If it mounts properly, go ahead and try to repair it with DiskUtility. If it doesn't then sometimes by restarting the computer and going into the recovery partition may be able to give you better results, since it's loading OSX to the RAM instead. Be careful not to mess with other disks/partitions.

You can also try to repair it manually in Terminal. To do this, open a terminal window and do the following:

1. List volumes: `cd /Volumes`
2. Once you know the volume name (drive ID), type `diskutil verifyVolume [your volume name]`
3. If it doesn't give you any errors, then repair it: `diskutil repairvolume /Volumes/[your volume name]`

If after doing all this, you still have issues with your drive, I would try using a different Mac OS X computer (not Windows)

cheers

Comment: Thanks @megamaiku but today I found the solution that I've posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an HDD disappear from Finder on a Mac Computer.  When tested on a Windows 7 computer it showed up but appeared empty.  A Windows 10 computer was unable to see the drive.
I used the Windows 7 computer to run EaseusDataRecovery and then to format the drive to NTFS, the only option available.  I then connected the drive to the Mac Computer and formatted it again.  I can now use the drive with any of the three computers.